# UISlider thumbRect interferes with UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uislider

I encountered some strange behaviour of the UISlider when I put some UIButtons next to it. The slider's thumb interferes with the buttons in a way I don't really understand.

Whenever the slider's thumb is close to the button, there seems to be an invisible area which prevents the button to react to touch events. When the slider's thumb stays below the button the button recognizes touch events, but there still seems to be a thin area above and below the slider's thumb which will block the button and lets you drag the slider's thumb. I do not get the logic behind this.

**UISlider interferes with UIButton**

[image]

My UISlider subclass looks like this:

```
import UIKit

class MySlider: UISlider {

    @IBInspectable var height: CGFloat = 5

    override func trackRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {

        return CGRect(origin: bounds.origin, size: CGSize(width: bounds.width, height: height))
    }

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {

        let tr = self.trackRect(forBounds: self.bounds)
        if tr.contains(point) {
            print("hit")
            return self
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

**UISlider hitTest**

[image]

The hitTest returns the UIView when the tracRect is touched but also when a thin area above and below the thumbImage is touched.

I searched a lot about this issue and played around with the class functions thumbRect, point and beginTracking but it doesn't change that behaviour. It doesn't seem to be well documented which area excactly is being affected by the UISlider.

I would much appreciate any explanation on that topic.

Comment: I think you have two choices here: (1) Keep the tight layout and bring the slider subview to the front or (2) change the layout, possibly by making the buttons smaller - and you *could* check the main view's bounds to decide when.

Comment: I agree, you should always leave some space between UISliders and other UI elements which should respond to touch events. But I would like to know how much space this exactly should be. Even the third UIButton on the bottom of the image is affected by the slider's thumb. And there is some space left but obviously not enough.

Comment: Well, that's where auto layout comes in. (1) Using leading/trailing/top/bottom anchors **you** define the exact amount of space left between views. (2) Then using height/width, guides, and container views (along with prioritizing) you define the remainder.

Comment: Yes, that is common practice. But do you know how much space actually gets affected by a UISlider's thumb element? Is that documented anywhere? And if there are values which you can rely on are there any methods which allow to change these values? Besides that, I would like to understand the logic behind the behaviour shown in the screen capture above.

Comment: I know that the "standard" UISlider has a height you cannot change, and 30 points is the number that comes to my mind. I worked for almost a month on fitting 4 sliders with labels - 2x2 in portrait, 4x1 in landscape - along with a UISegmentedControl and a GLKView. Now, if you wish you can set a custom thumb image (in code only) that *should* make for a smaller height if you'd like. Look at the volume slider in iTunes for an example. Oddly enough, when I did this, in IB (I made it IBDesignable) I only saw the top half of the thumb image! One last comment coming....

Comment: I can think of two things behind the behavior. First - HIG (Human Interface Guidelines). Back in the day it ruled. Come iOS (iPhone 2 days) it still did. Apple clearly spoke of how "thick" or "fat" a touch is - 40 points if I recall. One of my favorite games has a major annoyance: buttons that are half that height. It's a real PIA to start a new game. So at 30 points, a UISlider already *is* smaller than many other elements. Second, the Z-axis or view hierarchy., along with the UISlider frame, which is rectangular. I wouldn't guarantee anything when a slider overlays a UIButton.